# не получается сделать построчное чтение файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Просьба:** не выходит переделать код под номером 1) на построчное,а не мгновенное чтение файла (попытка под номером 2)

**код выполняет следующую задачу** : Написать программу, которая читая последовательность чисел из файла, выводит на экран самую длинную возрастающую последовательность, ее длину и позицию (в числах и символах) с которой она началась.

1)

```
import time,os,string,psutil,re
start_time = time.time()
symbol_len = 1  # Размер буфера чтения
res_list = []

with open('111.txt','r+') as file:
    s = str(file.read())
    s = re.sub('[^\d]', '', s)
if  not s:
    print("файл пуст!")
else:
    print("Введена последовоательность :",s)
    res = ''
    i = 0

    while i < len(s):
        if res == '' or (int(res[-1]) < int(s[i])):
            res += s[i]
        else:
            res_list.append(res)
            res = s[i]
        i += 1

    res_list.append(res)
    _max = max(res_list, key=len)
    print(f'Самая длинная восх. посл. - {_max}\nсимволов - {len(_max)}\nначальный индекс - {s.find(_max)}')
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print("Программа занимает ", process.memory_info().rss /1048576,"мбайт")  # in bytes
    print("--- %s Секунд выполнялась программа  ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

2. 

```
import time,os,string,psutil,re
start_time = time.time()
symbol_len = 1  # Размер буфера чтения
res_list = []


with open('111.txt','r+') as file:
    d = file.read(symbol_len)  # Считываем первый символ
    if not d:  # Обработка исключения пустого файла
        print("\nФайл text.txt пустой.")
    else:
        i = 0
        res = ''
        for s in file.readlines():
            while i < len(s):
                if res == '' or (int(res[-1]) < int(s[i])):
                    res += s[i]
                else:
                    res_list.append(res)
                    res = s[i]
                    i += 1

    res_list.append(res)
    _max = max(res_list, key=len)
    print(f'Самая длинная восх. посл. - {_max}\nсимволов - {len(_max)}\nначальный индекс - {s.find(_max)}')
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print("Программа занимает ", process.memory_info().rss /1048576,"мбайт")  # in bytes
    print("--- %s Секунд выполнялась программа  ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Что именно означает "построчное чтение"? readlines вообще читает строчки отдельно

Answer (score 1):

Вечер добрый. Попробуйте readline(). Так как readline**s**() считывает сразу все строки в список, в то время как readline() считывает отдельно каждую строку.
https://pythonru.com/osnovy/chtenie-iz-fajla-postrochno-v-python

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open('111.txt','r+') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        print(line.rstrip())
```

В чём проблема считать файл с помощью `.readlines()`?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправите отступы в вашем коде. Иначе он не будет работать.

Comment: Когда используете `with`, не надо применять  `readlines()`, вторая строка может быть просто `for line in file:`

Comment: @MarianD Скорее речь про `for`, а не про `with`, от использования `with` работа с файлом никак не меняется кроме того, что его не нужно самому закрывать )  А вот если использовать `for`, то да, в `readlines` тут смысла нет, только зря место на память под все строки тратится.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, вы прав, спасибо за поправку.